# Big-O notation with 2 variables. Given m <= n, can we reduce O(nm)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Assuming `m <= n`, can you reduce `O(nm)` to `O(n)`?

I would think not, since `m` can be equal to `n`

In the case of `m < n`, I would think that `O(nm)` can be reduced to `O(n)` since `m` is strictly less than `n` and hence becomes insignificant as `n` approaches infinity

Am I correct in my above assumptions? If so, why? What is the more formal way of showing this?

Comment: No, m<n could mean m=n-1, in which case m would still be significant. A formal way would be to impose a big-oh, omega, or theta bound on m with respect to n (e.g. m=O(log n)) then it works out

Comment: Without more information, `O(mn)` should stay. You could write it's also `O(n**2)` but you'd lose information. If `m` were bounded, you could write `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `m` is a constant (E.g.: `2`) or lower than a constant, you are right: `O(mn) = O(n)`.

But because you wrote `m < n`, I suppose that `m` also goes to infinite, but slower than `n`.

In this case, you are wrong.

Consider `m = log(n)` as an example and everything should be clear.

```
O(mn) = O(n*log(n))
```

which is different than `O(n)`.

That would be true for `O(m+n)`, but not for `O(mn)`.

Comment: @EricDuminil , I edited the post to cover both cases.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Given `m <= n`, all you can say about `O(mn)` is that it's `O(n**2)` at worst.

If `m` is bounded by a constant, `O(mn)` becomes `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can not reduce the `O(m*n)` to `O(n)`. If there is no boundary condition on `m`.

`m < n` It means m can be anything between `0` to `n-1`.

Let's say that `m` is bounded and it value ca not grow more than `C`

```
m <= C
```

In this case

```
O(m*n) can be reduced to O(n)
```

P.S : Do read this [plain english big o notaion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)